Speingboot httpclient adds duplicate cookie header
I am using spring boot rest template to make http call to our server. I have below code to use restTemplate
ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity  = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, returnType);
request entity contains request body, headers (including Cookie header) etc. When request is made, I can see 2 'Cookie' headers are present. I am adding one for custom Cookie and one gets added by RequestAddCookies interceptor which is part httpclient library. This is causing issue for me as I have 2 Cookie headers. How can I avoid the Cookies being added by springboot?

Disabling cookie management - disableCookieManagement() on Http Client resolved the issue.
